# In modern CPUs, is the etched chip face-up in the packaging?

Tags: integrated-circuit, microprocessor, chip-design

I know that the integrated circuits of the 1980s had the etched chip glued face-up inside the packaging, with tiny gold wires bridging the open space from the top surface of the chip, down to contact pads around the perimeter of the chip.

I do not know anything about modern desktop/server processor design, but it seems like with the high density of connections, it would be impractical to internally rearrange the contacts in rings, with hundreds of gold filaments around the perimeter, using the old interconnect method.

Is the etched side now placed face-down, in direct contact with the dense array of contact pads? And if so, what is used to mass-connect the etched silicon to the contact pads?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_chip

Comment: Thanks, that then leads me to the full name of what companies like Intel are doing: "Flip Chip - Land Grid Array x" ... Flip Chip with a subcarrier connection board under the chip, rather than directly bonding it to the final circuit board.

Comment: Due to the high pin-count of modern CPUs, bonding is not possible as all connections need to be on the edge of the chip. Bonding requires some minimum spacing which limits how much connections can be made. With flip-chip techniques this can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Face down is called flip-chip design. It also has pads (big pieces of metal not covered by silicon oxide) but in contrast to the old way the pads are spread over the surface of the chip. They are connected like the bal-grid array chips to the pads but then inside the package. 
Try a search engine in 'image' mode with the term 'flip chip'.
One more thing. this is only for big chips in very large volume. Smaller ones are still using a pad ring and bond wires.